# UI freezes when I try to access a remote server. The activity references a service to access remote server

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I am trying to start a service from an activity and that service is supposed to access a remote server. In the activity I have an animation to indicate to the user that there is some sort of progress in the background. The problem I am having is that the animation just becomes still, it freezes while the user is waiting for a response. I have tried everything and I am 
not sure how to solve this.

The code in myActivity

```
Intent remoteService = new Intent(context, MyService.class);             
startService(remoteService);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a service is a component without UI doesn't mean it runs on a background thread.

If your `MyService` class extends `Service` then it will be running on the UI thread, therefore blocking the activity/UI

`IntentService` is a `Service`, that manages a background thread used to execute the `onHandleIntent` method, however is not suitable for long running tasks.